# Подсчет гласных и согласных в строке

Tags: python

Есть код, который запрашивает кол-во строк для ввода стихотворения, а затем считает общее кол-во гласных и согласных.

```
quest = int(input('Сколько будет строк? '))
gls = 0
sgl = 0
vse_gls = ["а", "е", "ё", "и", "о", "у", "ы", "э", "ю", "я"]
count = 0
while quest > count:
    poem = input()
    for i in poem:
        if i.isalpha():
            if i in vse_gls:
                gls += 1
            else:
                sgl += 1
    count += 1

print('Кол-во гласных:', gls)
print('Кол-во согласных:', sgl)
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы он считал гласные и согласные еще и отдельно для каждой строки?

Comment: Перенесите оба оператора print внутрь цикла while (перед count += 1) и будете получить ответ по каждой строке. Только не забудьте после вывода еще и обнулять оба счетчика, разумеется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного избыточен ваш код.

Первое, не зачем считать количество строк. Для `while` необходимо определить условие выхода и все. Причина в том, что у вас не определяется поведение если будет расхождение когда вы определеяете количество строк, а потом когда вводите эти строки. Здесь в легую можно ошибиться. И даже если программа введет себя корректно, то, что будет если я введу количество строк в пару миллиардов. Шутников много, поэтому не стоит давать им шанс). Конечно, если это только не условие задачи...

Второе, для каждой строки считать количество гласных и согласных и помещять в списки. В конце суммировать и будет общий результат.

Третье, строку можно очистить от всего ненужного и привести к строчным буквам

```py
gls = "аеиоуюя"
gls_each_line = []
sgl_each_line = []

while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        f = filter(str.isalpha, line)
        clear_letter_low = "".join(f).lower()
        gls_count = 0
        for letter in gls:
            gls_count += clear_letter_low.count(letter)
        sgl_each_line.append(len(clear_letter_low) - gls_count)
        gls_each_line.append(gls_count)
    else:
        break

for i in range(len(sgl_each_line)):
    s = f"В строке номер {i+1}: гласных {gls_each_line[i]}, с согласных {sgl_each_line[i]}"
    print(s)
    
print(f"В тексте {sum(gls_each_line)} гласных и {sum(sgl_each_line)} согласных")
```

Несколько комментариев по коду.

1. `gls_each_line` и `sgl_each_line` переменные будут копить количество гласных и согласных для каждой строки
2. `while` будет запрашивать строку до тех пор пока, не получит пустую строку, т.е. нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd> и программа завершится
3. Для того чтобы очистить строку применяю фильтр только по буквам, результат работы фильтра привожу к строчным буквам и кладу в переменную `clear_letter_low`

```py
f = filter(str.isalpha, line)
clear_letter_low = "".join(f).lower()
```

Пример, как это работает

```py
line = "Не важно какаЯ СТРОКа 78900 и ЧТОБЫ она не сОДЕРжала"
f = filter(str.isalpha, line)
clear_letter_low = "".join(f).lower()
print(clear_letter_low)

# out
# неважнокакаястрокаичтобыонанесодержала
```

на выходе имеем только буквы в нужном регистре.

4. Считаем гласные -> помещяем в накопитель `gls_each_line`. Из длины чистой строки вычитаем количество гласных и результат помещяем в `sgl_each_line`
5. Чтобы вывести количество гласных/согласных из всего текста, просто применяем метод для суммирования элементов списка `sum()`

Проверяем

```
# входные данные
Затем генератор распаковывается в готовую
вляются неизменяемыми объектами, поэтому
все вышеуказаные методы убирает символы 
з данной строки и возвращает новую, они не меняют состояние

# выходные данные
В строке номер 1: гласных 16, с согласных 21
В строке номер 2: гласных 16, с согласных 20
В строке номер 3: гласных 14, с согласных 21
В строке номер 4: гласных 23, с согласных 26
В тексте 69 гласных и 88 согласных
```

Answer (score 1):

Ввод:

```
> Люблю грозу в начале мая,
> Когда весенний, первый гром,
> как бы резвяся и играя,
> Грохочет в небе голубом.
> exit
```

Вывод:

```
Люблю грозу в начале мая,    | {'Гласные: ': 9, 'Согласные: ': 11, 'Иные символы: ': 1}
Когда весенний, первый гром,     | {'Гласные: ': 8, 'Согласные: ': 15, 'Иные символы: ': 2}
как бы резвяся и играя,      | {'Гласные: ': 9, 'Согласные: ': 9, 'Иные символы: ': 1}
Грохочет в небе голубом.     | {'Гласные: ': 8, 'Согласные: ': 12, 'Иные символы: ': 1}
Общее число гласных: 34
Общее число согласных: 47
Общее число иных символов: 5
```

Код:

```
import os

vse_gls = ["а", "е", "ё", "и", "о", "у", "ы", "э", "ю", "я"]
vse_sgl = ['б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'x', 'ш', 'щ', 'ч']

print('Когда заходить закончить ввод введите exit')
input('> нажмите ENTER что бы продолжить')

totalGls = 0
totalSgl = 0
totalOtherSymbols = 0
strings = {}

os.system('cls')

while True:
    Gls = 0
    Sgl = 0
    otherSymbols = 0

    userString = input('> ')

    if userString.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        for i in range(len(userString)):
            if userString[i].lower() in vse_gls:
                totalGls += 1
                Gls += 1
            elif userString[i].lower() in vse_sgl:
                Sgl += 1
                totalSgl += 1
            elif userString[i].lower() == ' ':
                pass
            else:
                otherSymbols += 1
                totalOtherSymbols += 1
    strings.update({userString: {'Гласные: ': Gls, 'Согласные: ': Sgl, 'Иные символы: ': otherSymbols}})

os.system('cls')

keysList = list(strings.keys())

for i in range(len(keysList)):
    print(f'{keysList[i]} \t | {strings[keysList[i]]}')

print(f'Общее число гласных: {totalGls}\nОбщее число согласных: {totalSgl}\nОбщее число иных символов: {totalOtherSymbols}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = int(input("Сколько будет строк: "))
gls = 0
sogls = 0
vse_gls = ["а", "е", "ё", "и", "о", "у", "ы", "э", "ю", "я"]
for _ in range(rows):
    line = input("Введите строку: ")
    for i in line:
        if i in vse_gls:
            gls += 1
        else:
            """Проверяем на наличе постороних символов в строке"""
            if i!=" " or i!="." or i!=",":
                sogls +=1


print(f"Гласных: {gls}\nСогласных: {sogls}")
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем все так усложнять????

Элементарное исправление в коде и все требования задания выполнены:

```
quest = int(input('Сколько будет строк? '))
gls = sgl=0
vse_gls = ["а", "е", "ё", "и", "о", "у", "ы", "э", "ю", "я"]
count = 0
while quest > count:
    ls=gl=0
    poem = input()
    for i in poem:
        if i.isalpha():
            if i in vse_gls:
                ls += 1
            else:
                gl += 1
    print('Кол-во гласных:', ls,'Кол-во согласных:', gl)
    gls+=ls
    sgl+=gl
    count += 1

print('Кол-во гласных во всем тексте:', gls,'Кол-во согласных во всем тексте:', sgl)
```

Результат:

```
Сколько будет строк? 4

Люблю грозу в начале мая,
Кол-во гласных: 9 Кол-во согласных: 11

Когда весенний, первый гром,
Кол-во гласных: 8 Кол-во согласных: 15

как бы резвяся и играя,
Кол-во гласных: 9 Кол-во согласных: 9

Грохочет в небе голубом.
Кол-во гласных: 8 Кол-во согласных: 12
Кол-во гласных во всем тексте: 34 Кол-во согласных во всем тексте: 47
```